# send push notification for windows phone 7 using java

Tags: java, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I want to implement mobile notification with for my mobile application for windows 7 platform As I want to use java servlet to respond Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS) can any one help to convert below c# code in java

```
  protected void ButtonSendToast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the URI that the Microsoft Push Notification Service returns to the push client when creating a notification channel.
            // Normally, a web service would listen for URIs coming from the web client and maintain a list of URIs to send
            // notifications out to.
            string subscriptionUri = TextBoxUri.Text.ToString();


            HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

            // Create an HTTPWebRequest that posts the toast notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
            // HTTP POST is the only method allowed to send the notification.
            sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

            // The optional custom header X-MessageID uniquely identifies a notification message. 
            // If it is present, the same value is returned in the notification response. It must be a string that contains a UUID.
            // sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", "<UUID>");

            // Create the toast message.
            string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
               "<wp:Toast>" +
                    "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                    "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                    "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" +
               "</wp:Toast> " +
            "</wp:Notification>";

            // Set the notification payload to send.
            byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toastMessage);

            // Set the web request content length.
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");


            using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
            }

            // Send the notification and get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
            string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
            string notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
            string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

            // Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
            // Normally, error handling code would be here. In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
            // notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
            TextBoxResponse.Text = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TextBoxResponse.Text = "Exception caught sending update: " + ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*** ***the answer may be out of date*** ***

You should use `java-mpns` lib to do this easier.

Here is the code: https://github.com/plucury/java-mpns

Comment: I have one question question. Can we send push notifications to windows phone 8.1 using java-mpns? please clarify this.

Comment: @bhadram I‘m not sure. Since it wasn't updated for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for giving the reply for that.I will look for alternatives. :)